# Differential operator equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this equation:

$\left( \frac{d}{dx}+ a\right)^{n+1} Z(x)=0$

with the following initial conditions:

$Z(0)=0$

$\hspace{10mm}\vdots$

$\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}Z(x)_{|x=0}=0$

$\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}Z(x)_{|x=0}=1$

My idea is that the operators $\frac{d}{dx}$ and $a$ commute so I can apply the Newton binome formula:

$\left( \frac{d}{dx}+ a\right)^{n+1}=\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}+(n+1)a\frac{d^{n}}{dx^{n}}+\frac{(n+1)n}{2}a^2\frac{d^{n-1}}{dx^{n-1}}+\dots+(n+1)a^n\frac{d}{dx}+a^{n+1}$

And then I can multiply both sides for $e^{- ax}$

But then I cannot go on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that, as an operator,
\begin{equation*}
(\partial _{x}+a)^{n}=\left( \exp [-ax]\partial _{x}\exp [ax]\right)
^{n}=\exp [-ax]\partial _{x}^{n}\exp [ax]
\end{equation*}
so
\begin{eqnarray*}
\exp [-ax]\partial _{x}{}^{n+1}\exp [ax]Z(x) &=&0 \\
\partial _{x}{}^{n+1}\exp [ax]Z(x) &=&0
\end{eqnarray*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\exp [ax]Z(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}d^{k}x^{k},\;Z(x)=\exp
[-ax]\sum_{k=0}^{n}d_{k}x^{k}
\end{equation*}
From
\begin{eqnarray*}
(\partial _{x}^{k}Z)(0) &=&0,\;k=0,\cdots ,n-1, \\
(\partial _{x}^{n}Z)(0) &=&1
\end{eqnarray*}
we can then obtain the coefficients $d_{k}$

Answer (score 0):

Things get clearer when you observe that $$(\frac d{dx}+a)(\frac {x^n}{n!}e^{-ax})=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}e^{-ax}-a\frac {x^n}{n!}e^{-ax}+a\frac {x^n}{n!}e^{-ax}.$$